# Как создать хеш и подписать его с помощью утилиты cryptcp в КриптоПро?

Tags: linux, криптография, криптопро

Мне нужно вычислить хэш-сумму используя ГОСТ Р 34.11-2012, а потом хэш-сумму подписать с помощью ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012. Подскажите какой командой сделать это на Linux? Сейчас я делаю следующие команды:

```
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/cryptcp -dir /tmp -hash /tmp/hash_kOdlsl
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/cryptcp -sign -dn E=myemail@inbox.ru /tmp/hash_kOdlsl.hsh
```

Вроде получаю два хеша, но при прохождении проверки получаю ответ "Подпись неверная".

Заменил на следующие команды, мне кажутся они вернее, но ответ тот же:

```
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/csptest -keyset -hash GOST12_256 -silent -cont '\\.\HDIMAGE\te-f9172e97-7dec-4b7c-a6d1-e11fadd1e993' -keytype exchange -in /tmp/hash_kOdlsl -hashout /tmp/hash_kOdlsl.hsh
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/csptest -keyset -sign GOST12_256 -silent -cont '\\.\HDIMAGE\te-f9172e97-7dec-4b7c-a6d1-e11fadd1e993' -keytype exchange -in /tmp/hash_kOdlsl -out /tmp/hash_kOdlsl.sig
```

Comment: попробуй команду `-signf` она подписывает через хэш файла

Comment: @eri не помогло

Comment: а я сломал криптопро у себя на ноуте - вообще перестало работать. починю - пропробую повторить

Comment: @eri второй вариант рабочий, первый не проверял. Просто, там, где осуществлялась проверка, установили неправильный сертификат.

Answer (score 1):

Вы нашли решение? Я заметил, что команда:

```
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/csptest -keyset -hash GOST12_256 -silent -cont '\\.\HDIMAGE\te-f9172e97-7dec-4b7c-a6d1-e11fadd1e993' -keytype exchange -in /tmp/hash_kOdlsl -hashout /tmp/hash_kOdlsl.hsh
```

использует `34.10-2012` вместо `34.11-2012`

Comment: хм. у меня все работает отлично. возможно в сертификате у вас так указано, что хэш создается в 34.10.